# like if x=y, select yes, if x !=y, select no ms access

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm new to access, and have a large amount of data, which includes payment details, and i need to know whether or not someone has paid.

Is there a way to set something up,

```
like if x=y, select yes, if x !=y, select no
```

for a yes/no field, that does it automatically, rather than me going down and checking whether or  not they have?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `iif()`:

```
select iif(x = y, 'yes', 'no')
```

Comment: Hey, when i put that select iif() in, it brings up and error message saying: The syntax of this subquery in this expression is incorrect. any ideas? sorry, im quite new to this xD

Comment: Dont worry, i figured it out, it needed a semi colon not a comma in between the parts :) thanks